# Is it possible to use a common menu across two websites by importing it from the first to the second?

Tags: php, copyright, menu

We pay a service to host both our website and our blog. The blog is on the WordPress platform. Both sites are designed to look similar (as best we could) since they are our company websites. The web developer of our main portfolio site has done a wonderful job. I would like the menu from our main site to appear exactly the same on our WP site so that everything appears continuous. Both are hosted on the same server, but I don't think they are in the same location. Is there a way to capture the menu from our main site and display that on our WP blog?

Do I need to get the style sheet and code for the menu? Is it possible to have it automatically take those parts from our main site so that if we update the menu on our main site, it automatically changes on the blog? Keep in mind, they are technically separate domains (from what I understand).

Comment: You tagged this [Tag:copyright], but since you own both sites you should own the copyright on them.   You can copy content from one to another at will from a legal standpoint.

Comment: My reason for tagging it as copyright is that technically we don't own both ends. We pay our Webdesigner and he retains his code as proprietary. In that case, I am only paying a use fee and don't really have "rights" to the his code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use external stylesheet to inherit same design, on multiple website.

```
<LINK href="/path/menu-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

1. Copy your menu-style design into one css file, and named it menu-style.css.
2. Host menu-style.css file in your server ex. domain.com/path/menu-style.css
3. Add external style sheet link (Above code), to wordpress head section.
4. Change WordPress menu class name to external stylesheet class name.